# How can I determine the exact meaning of a word in a sentence?

Tags: nlp, nltk, semantics, wordnet, word-sense-disambiguation

By saying `determine the meaning` here I mean selecting a lemma produced by NLTK-like natural language toolkit according to the syntactic function and semantic meaning in the sentence.

By way of illustration, in the following sentence:

> Smartphones have grown to be the most essential piece of modern
>   technology, and yet the industry manufacturing them has **backed**
>   itself into a corner where only two comopanies, Apple and Samsung, are
>   generating any reliable profit.

For the word `backed`, NLTK provides 12 lemmas:

> 1. back.v.01 be behind; approve of
> 2. back.v.02 travel backward
> 3. second.v.01 give support or one's approval to
> 4. back.v.04 cause to travel backward
> 5. back.v.05 support financial backing for
> 6. back.v.06 be in back of
> 7. bet_on.v.01 place a bet on
> 8. back.v.08 shift to a counterclockwise direction
> 9. back.v.09 establish as valid or genuine
> 10. back.v.10 strengthen by providing with a back or backing
> 11. backed.a.01 having a back or backing, usually of a specified type
> 12. backed.s.02 used of film that is coated on the side opposite the emulsion with a substance to absorb light

How can I let the machine automatically help me choose one?

Comment: Try `word sense disambiguation`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31959690/choosing-appropriate-sense-of-a-word-from-wordnet and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613773/anyone-know-of-some-good-word-sense-disambiguation-software