# Implementing skip gram with scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is there any way to implement skip-gram in `scikit-learn` library?
I have manually generated a list with n-skip-grams, and pass that to skipgrams as vocabulary for the `CountVectorizer()` method.

Unfortunately, its performance on prediction is very poor: only 63% accuracy.
However, I get an accuracy of 77-80% on `CountVectorizer()` using `ngram_range(min,max)`from the default code.

Is there a better way to implement skip-grams in scikit learn?

Here is my part of code:

```
corpus = GetCorpus() # This one get text from file as a list

vocabulary = list(GetVocabulary(corpus,k,n))  
# this one returns a k-skip n-gram   

vec = CountVectorizer(
          tokenizer=lambda x: x.split(),
          ngram_range=(2,2),
          stop_words=stopWords,
          vocabulary=vocabulary)
```

Answer (score 12):

To vectorize text with skip-grams in scikit-learn simply passing the skip gram tokens as the vocabulary to `CountVectorizer` will not work. You need to modify the way tokens are processed which can be done with a custom analyzer. Below is an example vectorizer that produces 1-skip-2-grams,

```
from toolz import itertoolz, compose
from toolz.curried import map as cmap, sliding_window, pluck
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

class SkipGramVectorizer(CountVectorizer):
    def build_analyzer(self):    
        preprocess = self.build_preprocessor()
        stop_words = self.get_stop_words()
        tokenize = self.build_tokenizer()
        return lambda doc: self._word_skip_grams(
                compose(tokenize, preprocess, self.decode)(doc),
                stop_words)

    def _word_skip_grams(self, tokens, stop_words=None):
        # handle stop words
        if stop_words is not None:
            tokens = [w for w in tokens if w not in stop_words]

        return compose(cmap(' '.join), pluck([0, 2]), sliding_window(3))(tokens)
```

For instance, on [this Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram#Skip-gram),

```
text = ['the rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain']

vect = SkipGramVectorizer()
vect.fit(text)
vect.get_feature_names()
```

this vectorizer would yield the following tokens,

```
['falls on',  'in falls',  'mainly the',  'on plain',
 'rain spain',  'spain mainly',  'the in']
```

Comment: Thank for your reply , bro. I will try it soon and let you know about it.

Answer (score 7):

I came up with my own implementation of a skip-gram vectorizer. It is inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31902507/1618893) post. I also limited skip-grams to not cross sentence boundaries (using `nltk.sent_tokenize`), to limit the feature space. Here is my code:

```
import nltk
from itertools import combinations
from toolz import compose
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

class SkipGramVectorizer(CountVectorizer):

    def __init__(self, k=1, **kwds):
        super(SkipGramVectorizer, self).__init__(**kwds)
        self.k=k

    def build_sent_analyzer(self, preprocess, stop_words, tokenize):
        return lambda sent : self._word_skip_grams(
                compose(tokenize, preprocess, self.decode)(sent),
                stop_words)

    def build_analyzer(self):    
        preprocess = self.build_preprocessor()
        stop_words = self.get_stop_words()
        tokenize = self.build_tokenizer()
        sent_analyze = self.build_sent_analyzer(preprocess, stop_words, tokenize)

        return lambda doc : self._sent_skip_grams(doc, sent_analyze)

    def _sent_skip_grams(self, doc, sent_analyze):
        skip_grams = []
        for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(doc):
            skip_grams.extend(sent_analyze(sent))
        return skip_grams

    def _word_skip_grams(self, tokens, stop_words=None):
        """Turn tokens into a sequence of n-grams after stop words filtering"""
        # handle stop words
        if stop_words is not None:
            tokens = [w for w in tokens if w not in stop_words]

        # handle token n-grams
        min_n, max_n = self.ngram_range
        k = self.k
        if max_n != 1:
            original_tokens = tokens
            if min_n == 1:
                # no need to do any slicing for unigrams
                # just iterate through the original tokens
                tokens = list(original_tokens)
                min_n += 1
            else:
                tokens = []

            n_original_tokens = len(original_tokens)

            # bind method outside of loop to reduce overhead
            tokens_append = tokens.append
            space_join = " ".join

            for n in xrange(min_n,
                            min(max_n + 1, n_original_tokens + 1)):
                for i in xrange(n_original_tokens - n + 1):
                    # k-skip-n-grams
                    head = [original_tokens[i]]                    
                    for skip_tail in combinations(original_tokens[i+1:i+n+k], n-1):
                        tokens_append(space_join(head + list(skip_tail)))
        return tokens

def test(text, ngram_range, k):
    vectorizer = SkipGramVectorizer(ngram_range=ngram_range, k=k)
    vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
    print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

def main():
    text = ['Insurgents killed in ongoing fighting.']

    # 2-skip-bi-grams
    test(text, (2,2), 2)
    # 2-skip-tri-grams
    test(text, (3,3), 2)
###############################################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This would generate the following feature names:

```
[u'in fighting', u'in ongoing', u'insurgents in', u'insurgents killed', u'insurgents ongoing', u'killed fighting', u'killed in', u'killed ongoing', u'ongoing fighting']
[u'in ongoing fighting', u'insurgents in fighting', u'insurgents in ongoing', u'insurgents killed fighting', u'insurgents killed in', u'insurgents killed ongoing', u'insurgents ongoing fighting', u'killed in fighting', u'killed in ongoing', u'killed ongoing fighting']
```

Notice, that I basically took the `_word_ngrams` function from the `VectorizerMixin` class and replaced the line

```
tokens_append(space_join(original_tokens[i: i + n]))
```

with the following:

```
head = [original_tokens[i]]                    
for skip_tail in combinations(original_tokens[i+1:i+n+k], n-1):
    tokens_append(space_join(head + list(skip_tail)))
```